# shrink a raster file in R

Tags: r, raster

I have a large number of large image files that I would like merge together but run into memory issues.  I would like to resave them all as a shrunken version. Then, merge the newer smaller versions together.

How can I shrink a raster object? Say I want to work with `volcano`:

```
library(raster)

vol  <- raster(volcano)

object.size(volcano)
# 42672 bytes

# I would expect to be able to use a function to shrink it here 
# to retain the CRS and have it represent a matrix of a smaller size.
```

Comment: Can you provide more info about volcano? E.g. dtype, rows, cols, ...etc.

Comment: volcano is a default object with dimensions 87x61.

Comment: There should be no reason to run into `memory issues`. What are these issues?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it without losing information. Each cell has a value, which takes memory. You can free memory only by lowering the number of cells. if this approach is feasible to you, you can `aggregate()` each raster using several methods (e.g. bilinear interpolation). This gives a raster that has less cells with *averaged* values.

/E